# add datetime field value to integer field value in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Is it possible to add one datetime field value like `2013-06-22 09:46:00` to one or more integer field value like`1`(represents days column)`2`(represents hours column) then the result obtain after adding datetime value to integer must be in datetime form, so that i can compare with another datetime field value.
Like if i get the result after adding with the integer field `2013-06-23 11:46:00`, i wants to compare it with another datetime field value, so that if the result value is greater than the compared value then only it w'll give me result.

I know how it w'll work in php but i wants to do through query.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need the seperate columns? Thats just doubling the ammount of space required to insert a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is the MySQL's date_add() function - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add.

For example, DATE_ADD('2013-06-22 09:46:00', INTERVAL 1 DAY), where you may replace the date-time and day interval with the corresponding column names.

**UPDATE**
Let us assume, the date-time field is called FIELDA and the integer field is called FIELDB representing days, then the function might be called as:

```
DATE_ADD(FIELDA, INTERVAL FIELDB DAY);
```

If however the integer field represent hours, you may call it as:

```
DATE_ADD(FIELDA, INTERVAL FIELDB HOUR);
```

Hope above helps!

Comment: thanks..but here i don't have integer value, i have to pass day value from the field of same table.. will you please explain me how i can do that.

Comment: As i mentioned above, i have to add both day and hour and i am trying this `DATE_ADD(FIELDA, INTERVAL FIELDAY:FIELDHOUR DAY_HOUR);` but its not working

Comment: @KumariManisha, please try `DATE_ADD(FIELDA, INTERVAL 'FIELDDAY FIELDHOUR' DAY_HOUR);`

Comment: @KumariManisha, I'm not sure if you're getting an error? The exact syntax is as mentioned in my last comment - `DATE_ADD(FIELDA, INTERVAL 'FIELDDAY FIELDHOUR' DAY_HOUR);`, i.e. single quotes are required in the "interval" and there should be a space (instead of colon) between FIELDDAY AND FIELDHOUR